# Billing account issue while integrating Google places in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-places-api, google-places

I have been following the https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-development/google-places-gem-21e9e1aac491 tutorial and am having trouble integrating the Google Places gem with my code to fetch Google reviews for my application.
I have enabled Google places and got the respective API key. I have also enabled the business account and subscribed to 1-month free trial. However, I am getting this message now.

```
 You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started.
```

doctors_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @doctor = Doctor.find(params[:id])
    authorize @doctor, :manage?
    @doctor = @location = @doctor.decorate
    #tring out google reviews
    api_key = "My_key"
    @client = GooglePlaces::Client.new(api_key) 
  end
```

show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @client.spots(-33.8670522, 151.1957362, :name => 'italian') %></h1>
```

thanks in advance, cheers

Comment: Maybe check with their Support ? Normally with a free-trial you would be expected to enter your billing details which might include a card, address etc. A bill might be generated but you wont be charged for the first month(and charged beyond that if you havent cancelled within a month). Failure to do these might just make you a user but not actually subscribed to the free trial.

Comment: yes, I did that. I got a bill generated and also paid 1 INR for the subscription.